# Adding an additional SQL query which checks for duplicate records

Tags: sql

I am trying to add a query in my current SQL INSERT INTO statement. Below is my table and current sql statement.

I have 3 tables:

*Table1*: **UserID**, **Username**.

*Table2*: **UserID**, **Status**.

*Table3*: **UserID**, **Username**, **Issue**

Currently I only have a SELECT statement which fulfills the above 3 checks and INSERT the result into Table3:

```
    INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), t1.UserName
   , CASE
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
        WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is not DELETE'
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
           THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
     END
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
   OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
   OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
```

Now I wish to add in another additional check which is to check for duplicated userid, and insert **UserID, Username, and Issue 'Duplicated userid found'** for any duplicates found into Table3.

1. Check for same userid with same caps (e.g. E01 and E01 should not exist)
2. Check for same userid but different caps (e.g. E01 and e01 should not exist)

How should I add in this SQL query into my current SQL statement?

Comment: Will constraints on Table3 prevent you from `INSERT`ing a second record into the table with the same `UserID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to insert record with `Duplicated userid found` (which would cause duplicate UserId values in your `Table3`, you could use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), t1.UserName
   , CASE
        WHEN (t3user.UserId IS NOT NULL OR t3Status.UserId IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'Duplicated userid found'
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
        WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is DELETE'
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
          THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
     END AS Issue
   FROM table1 t1
   FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
   LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3user ON t1.UserID = t3user.UserId
   LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3status ON t2.UserId = t3status.UserId
   WHERE 
   (
      (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
         OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
         OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
   )
```